# Restrict File Types when selecting files in AppJar

Tags: python, appjar

I am creating a data import module and I need to restrict users to uploading only Excel workbooks. I'm using AppJar for the GUI

```
app = gui('File Selection', '600x600')
app.addImage("Company", "appJar/company.gif")
app.zoomImage("Company", -10)
app.addLabel('title', 'PowerPoint Data Import')
app.setFont(18)
app.addFileEntry('Data File')

def press(button):
    if button == "Cancel":
        app.stop
    else:
        entry = app.getEntry('Data File')
        print 'Data File:', entry
        wb = load_workbook(filename = entry, data_only = True)    
        DataImport(wb)
        pptxname = entry[:-5] + '.pptx'
        prs.save(pptxname)
        print "Import Complete"

app.addButtons(['Import', 'Cancel'], press)

app.go()
```

No error messages, but the system will allow any filetype to be selected, and I haven't been able to find a way to restrict it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this work, I had to create a separate button that set the value, rather than using the feature that added multiple buttons. A bit roundabout, I'm afraid.

```
def xlsxselect():
    xslxfile = app.openBox(title="Choose Import Data", dirName=None, fileTypes=[('excel worksheets', '*.xlsx')],
                           parent=None, multiple=False, mode='r')
    app.setEntry('xlsxfile', xslxfile, callFunction=False)
```